# How to count all defined childforms with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, parent-child

I tried to use Count() or Length to count how many `Can_ListCandidate` childfrom are opening. Then, if there is only 1 form run, it is still keeping. While if the number is more than 2, they all will be closed. However, there is no option for the `f.GetType() == typeof(Can_ListCandidate)` to return any number.

```
foreach(Form f in this.MdiChildren) {
  if (f.GetType() == typeof(Can_ListCandidate)) {
    f.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear to me what you're trying to do, but if you want to count with a predicate, you could use:

```
int count = MdiChildren.OfType<Can_ListCandidate>().Count();
```

which includes subclasses or

```
int count = MdiChildren.Count(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Can_ListCandidate));
```

which doesn't.

Neither of these will dispose the forms, of course...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to count the `Can_ListCandidate` form and where I can put your supporting script to my code?

Comment: @PMay1903: What do you mean by "supporting script"? That code will count the `MdiChildren` either which are `Can_ListCandidate` or subclasses, or exactly `Can_ListCandidate`. You can use it anywhere you've got access to `MdiChildren`... where does your current code live